# sharepoint columns in single line at item insert/edit

Tags: sharepoint

In sharepoint 2010 list items can be inserted easily, when we insert or edit an item all the list column values are aligned in vertical as usual. but i would like to show that these column values to be entered are aligned in horizontal way. like http://www19.speedyshare.com/Mcc2K/download/sharepoint-parallel-columns.JPG. I have searched plenty, but couldn't find any relevant material and i want to do it WITHOUT USING SHAREPOINT DESIGNER OR VISUAL STUDIO.

Answer (score 0):

couple of months back we wanted the same thing but we didn't find any suitable solution. One of the sharepoint guru suggested use to use designer because it is not a good idea to go for 3rd party solutions just for layout because 3rd party controls always have some limitations/issue which is not good for extensiblilty of product.

Comment: I have heard that we can use visual web parts and can use JQuery to change the layout/look and feel, I will work on it later. Thanks for the advice but our requirement is to do it without SPD.